# add a watermark to a powerbuilder data window

Tags: powerbuilder, watermark

we have some confidential reports that we would like to add a watermark to when the print them out -- anyone know if you want add a watermark in a powerbuilder datawindow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a picture on the background. Drop a picture control below the footer band, then on the position tab, select Background for layer. Right-click the picture and select Bring to top. You can now position the image anywhere on the page and the data will display over it. When you do this the position is absolute. If you position it to be at the center of an 8 1/2 x 11 page, that's where it will be. Another possibility is to put the image in the footer (leave the layer set to Band) if you want it at the bottom of the page.

Comment: This works GREAT! I wish I could share a picture of it with you but its confidential ;-)  Thanks for the help - very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

If you're using 11.5, all you have to do is go to the DataWindow properties pane, the Background tab, and change the Brush Mode to Picture and assign the File attribute below.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: Thanks for the info on 11.5, we are still on 10.5 

I am playing with just adding a text box with very light shading in the title that stipulates the data as confidential.  Of course my preference would be like in WORD where the watermark can be displayed across the page and not interfer with the text/data on the page. I could probably even leave this off until we go to a new version, but would prefer to have it there due to the sensitive nature of the data.

Comment: So, it sounds like, stealing from the current Windows 7 campaign, "PowerBuilder 11.5 was your idea." I've never done done what you're trying, but like Hugh says, putting the object in the Background band is key. (If it were me, I'd just put it in the footer, but maybe I'm just being lazy.)